# Why would the light switch control the fan and the fan switch control the light?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

We replaced  8 ceiling fans in our house and they all worked great until the last one.  It was wired correctly according to the directions, but now the switch that controlled the previous fan, controls the light and vice versa.  Is this a problem/ fire risk?  We are having trouble finding the answer to this.

Answer (score 4):

You've likely just swapped a couple wires, if you even *have* to do anything. If the fan and light are controlled by simple snap switches, then you don't really *have* to do anything (other than relearn which switch is which). If you have specialty fan controls and/or dimmers, you'll want to switch things around.

In the ceiling box above the fan, there should be a wire connected to the blue wire of the fan, and the black wire of the fan. You'll simply want to swap these wires. So take the wire that is connected to the blue fan wire, and attach it instead to the black fan wire. Then take the wire that was attached to the black fan wire, and connect it to the blue fan wire.

If the wiring is more complicated than I've described (or a remote module is used), please post some photos of the wiring before proceeding.

Comment: hubby insists he did it correctly but says he will check tonight.  The switches are old knobs that turn and have 3 different "settings".  It is a double switch with 2 of the same type of knobs.  Just wondering if we need try to redo something or if it is likely safe.

Comment: If the switches are controlling the wrong devices, then he didn't do it right. He might have followed the instructions, but the instructions are written for "typical" installations. There's no way for the author of the documentation to know what *your* wiring looks like. Tell your husband to suck it up, and fix it!

Comment: :)  I will.  I appreciate you help.  Thank you for answering so quickly.

Comment: If you aren't up for climbing the ladder and dismounting the fan, another choice might be to swap wires at the switches.